# How To Return a Result in Excel based on a specific text value that is found 2 or more times in a range of cells

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am using a spreadsheet to capture test results. There are multiple different cells where the users capture the result of the test for the specific sample they are testing (pass/fail/etc).

I want to have one cell show the overall conclusion of the test. The criteria I need for the calculation is as follows:
If there are >=2 different cells that have the value "Conclusion - Fail", then the overall result would be a fail. If there is only 1 "Conclusion - Fail", then it would be pass.

I figured this would be an easy if then statement, but I am having trouble getting this to work.

Please any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A100,"Conclusion - Fail")>=2,"Fail","Pass")`?

Comment: @BruceWayne dude post as an answer, I will delete mine, you beat me by 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks so much for the fast response and it worked!!!!! :-)

Comment: @ScottCraner - No worries! I never really know when I should post as an answer or just comment...will do next time though. (You're close to that 60k! :D )

Comment: Do you guys know how I could also add another IF statement to that so that If in that same range the conclusion was "Conclusion - Not Tested Sample Size", then the overall conclusion would be "Not Tested - Sample Size"?

Comment: You could add another if statement like: =IF(COUNTIF(A:A,"Conclusion - Not Tested Sample Size”)>0,”"Not Tested - Sample Size”,IF(COUNTIF(A:A,”Conclusion - Fail")>=2,"Fail","Pass”))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIF() inside the IF():

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,"Conclusion - Fail")>=2,"Fail","Pass")
```